# Trying to run python script in snow sight which connects to endpoints of API returns 'Failed to establish a new connection' error

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, python-sockets

We are trying to run python script in snow sight which connects to endpoints of API. We are receiving 'Failed to establish a new connection' error while doing so. I have created sample code to just connect to google in snow park. The sample python code below, without snow park runs well but it fails to connect while running in snow sight web UI in snowflake. Much needed help on this. Thanks in advance!!

**P.S below are the sample code in snow sight and its error in the snowflake**

**Code:**

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col
import requests

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
  url = "https://www.google.com/"
  res = requests.get(url)
  print(res)

  # Print a sample of the dataframe to standard output.
  # dataframe.show()

  # Return value will appear in the Results tab.
  return main
```

**Error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
> conn = connection.create_connection(
> File "urllib3/util/connection.py", line 72, in create_connection
> for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
> File "/usr/lib/python_udf/2ea5e02f17b08cc4ded0dc3a5c4124fe51cdcb5d9c141c6fcf0ec8e525830082/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
> for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
> socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(
> File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 403, in _make_request
> self._validate_conn(conn)
> File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1053, in _validate_conn
> conn.connect()
> File "urllib3/connection.py", line 363, in connect
> self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
> File "urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
> raise NewConnectionError(
> urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffff4c666580>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send
> resp = conn.urlopen(
> File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 798, in urlopen
> retries = retries.increment(
> File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
> raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
> urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffff4c666580>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> Worksheet, line 8, in main
> File "requests/api.py", line 73, in get
> return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
> File "requests/api.py", line 59, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
> File "requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
> File "requests/sessions.py", line 701, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
> File "requests/adapters.py", line 520, in send
> raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffff4c666580>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))

Answer (score 0):

Currently Snowflake doesn't allow for Python code that runs inside Snowflake account to access external network. While it is not specifically documented for Python Worksheets, the same restrictions from UDFs and Stored Procedures apply there as well.

Extract from docs that highlights this:

```
Handler code executes within a restricted engine. Neither your code nor the code in library methods that you use should employ any prohibited system calls, including:

...

Network access.

Note that while you can’t use a UDF handler to create sockets or access URLs, you can use a procedure handler to access resources on an external network by calling external functions. For more information, see Introduction to External Functions.
```

[Here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf-stored-procedure-security-practices#practices-for-procedure-and-udf-handlers) is the docs that explains the security practices.